# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/weave/weave.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, scope, weave

`systemctl status docker` shows active and running
`docker ps` will give this error

> cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/weave/weave.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: Could see server start with `docker version`?

Comment: try using sudo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of the socket indicates that your $DOCKER_HOST environment variable has been set to point at the [weave proxy](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/tasks/weave-docker-api/using-proxy/). The fact that it doesn't respond means that the weave proxy is not running.

There are two remedies:

1. You can clear the environment variable, so that you're talking directly to docker again. Try

`weave env --restore`

or if that doesn't appear to work,

`export DOCKER_HOST=`

2. Or, you can try to get the weave proxy to run, so that it's there to answer on the socket. Try the link above for instructions.